# What is formula for obtaining this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations, combinations

I'm new to this part of SE. I do not even know what I should put as a title (hopeful someone can help me edit). Here is my problem

I have a bus traveling from A to D (trip). On the way there is sub-trips B and C, et al. So the total trip parts will be AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, and CD. Now the number of stops will be changing (Other trip will be for example A-D like above, some A-F, and so on). In other word, I can have any number of stops for any particular trip.

I don't know which formula I can apply to reliably know amount of combinations I can have as sub-trips.

Above gives me 6 sub-trips with 4 stops, but I need a formula that I can use to reliably know of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With n stops, $\frac{n!}{(2!)(n-2)!}$ is the answer. Note that $n!:=n\cdot(n-1)\cdot\cdots1$

Comment: is that n-factorial divide by two then the answer is multiplies to (n-2)! right?

Comment: No. The (n-1)! is in denominator. Sorry for bad notation.

Comment: you mean n-2 right?

Comment: yes. I also added parenthesis to make the expression clear.

Comment: sure that makes it super clear. Just as side question, does math provide a way to do the real combination (not the number of it)? I mean the AB, AC et al part?

Comment: What do you mean by et al

Comment: With the formula we can obtain number of stops. But I wanted to know if there is "magic" to give the actual combination (which for ABC will be AB, AC, BC)

Comment: forget about this, I have to do it using some programming language.

Comment: if you do this multiplication (A+B+C+D)(A+B+C+D), and ignore the squared terms, then half of the remained terms constitute the desired answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here we have select any two stops from suppose $n$ terminals so we have a combination formila ${n \choose 2}=\frac{n!}{(2!)(n-2)!}$ hope its clear.

Comment: thanks for that. One thing I didn't think of is that two is fixed. Thank you for also reminding me that!

Comment: just one thing what is the name of the formula? Is it permutation?
I did these things long ago in college and I don't remember correctly

Comment: Your Welcome ....

Comment: Its combination 'C' nC2

Comment: Checking the difference on web it sounds like its a permutation

Comment: No permutations deals with arrangements rather than selection and selection is combination see web for difference